# Replacing middle of circuit outlet with doorbell transformer

Tags: wiring, receptacle, doorbell

I am replacing an outlet in the middle of a run with doorbell transformer. The outlet is not required for code and the transformer is one that is rated to be installed in a 2 gang box. Yes, I will be using a divider to separate the line voltage and low voltage lines.

I will be replacing the current box with a 2 gang box, and finish fishing the low voltage wires to the new box.

My question is, how do I continue feeding the down feed outlets with power? The two wires in the photo not connected feed the next outlet.

Can I simply wire nut the two blacks from the wall and one of the blacks of the transformer together, then wire nut the two whites and the other black from the transformer together and finally wire nut the grounds together?

**UPDATE**

So future viewers don't get confused by one of the below posts, this is possible using the components I have bought, which are the following:

[Edwards Signaling 593 Adapter](https://edwards-signals.com/index.cfm?pid=270)

[Edward Signaling 591 Transformer](https://edwards-signals.com/index.cfm?pid=104)

The NuTone transformer unfortunately was not an option for me because it is made to mount behind a chime, which I do not have. There wasn't a clean way to run the low voltage wires to my location because they come out the front of the component.

[image: doorbell transformer]

Comment: That's how I would do it. Presuming, of course, that you haven't removed a GFCI outlet for this.

Comment: Yes, as @FreeMan wrote. It's called pig tailing.You have to do a better job than in the picture: there should be no copper exposed at the rim of the nut.

Comment: Good catch, @P2000 that top wire in the left most wire nut doesn't even look like it's been captured by the threads.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, this was just to make sure that the doorbell worked before I tore everything out for no reason. I will be trimming the wires before wire nutting them in the box. Outlet is not a GFCI thankfully.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to find that replacing the box with a two gang box is more difficult that just adding a new one.

Your black wires along with one from the transformer will be wire nutted together. You white wires along with a black wire from the transformer will be wire nutted together. Then connect your grounds.

The single box will be connected to the framing studs somehow. You'll have to get in there with a keyhole saw or hack saw blade to cut the supports. Be careful not to damage the cables in the wall or screw up the drywall or you'll be touching up paint.

There are two types of old work boxes. One has tabs that hole it in place but you have to follow the template exactly or the box won't fit securely. The other type has screws already mounted in the box and is meant to be screwed into a stud. Those, IMHO, are the better ones to use.  See picture below.

[image]

Comment: Definitely would be easier, but I already have to do drywall patching and repaint the wall from fishing the wire so might as well do it clean and just have one box. I usually can just stick a screwdriver between the box and the stud and push against the stud to pry the old one out. I haven't seen these boxes before but thanks, they look much better and I will use one of those!